# What is the aberrant nature of my code? It is not getting redirected to appropriate page

Tags: asp.net, ajax

On some button clicks, I am using Ajax model pop up with the following code:

```
if (SurveyCount == 1)
{
    DateTime FreeSurveyDate = (DateTime)dtCountClientSurvey.Rows[0]["SurveyDate"];

    if ((DateTime.Now - FreeSurveyDate).Days > 90)
    {

        Session["YourAssessment"] = false;
        Session["MyAssessment"] = false;
        modelPopUp.Visible = true;
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/yourAssessment.aspx");
        Session["YourAssessment"] = true;
        Session["MyAssessment"] = false;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that, in `else` part, it is not redirecting to `yourAssessment.aspx` but post back to the same page.

Then, when I add a break point there, it moves to the `else` part and it stops debugging and complains the below:

```
Locating source for 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'. (No checksum.)
The file 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vc7\atlmfc'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vc7\crt'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'.
```

It has been quite a while and I am still unable to fix this error, and I am wondering what is the reason that it is not getting redirected?

Answer (score 1):

You code is fine. Problem is with Ajax control toolkit you are using. From the log you have provided it looks like one of the file (**ExtenderControlBase.cs**) of ajax toolkit is missing and hence is the issue.

probably you can consider re installing the Ajax toolkit.

> The debugger could not locate the source file
>   'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'.

Answer (score -3):

Remove Runat server tags from Ajax controls in your .aspx, Rebuild it. If it works then add the runat server tag again. It worked for me.

Comment: I know without a "runat" property,  server control doesn't work. But, I having no other solution, tried that and it worked.